# Search a Workbook for a string “datatoFind” beyond the first occurrence

Tags: vba, excel, search

I just posted this code yesterday with a different question, which was solved simply (thanks!). I'm trying to use a macro to search an excel document for a certain string. I want to take the addresses of the cells in which the string is found and put them one after the other in the i column of the current sheet. My problem is the macro only identifies the first occurrence of the string, and doesn't identify other instances, even though I know they exist. My code is below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find_Data()

Dim datatoFind As String
Dim rangeSearch As Range
Dim rangeLast As Range
Dim foundRange As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String
Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim sheetCounter As Integer
Dim currentSheet As Integer
Dim foundmatrixCounter As Integer
foundmatrixCounter = 2 'initialize this to the second row so the total can be placed in the first row when done

'set search range
Set rangeSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:X100")

'set last cell in range
Set rangeLast = rangeSearch.Cells(rangeSearch.Cells.Count)

currentSheet = ActiveSheet.Index
datatoFind = InputBox("Please enter the value to search for")
If datatoFind = "" Then Exit Sub
sheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For sheetCounter = 1 To sheetCount
    Sheets(sheetCounter).Activate
    Set foundRange = Cells.Find(What:=datatoFind, After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    'if datatoFind is found in search range
    If Not foundRange Is Nothing Then
        'save the address of the first occurrence of datatoFind, in the strFirstAddress variable
        strFirstAddress = foundRange.Address
        Do
            'Find next occurrence of datatoFind
            Set foundRange = foundRange.FindNext(foundRange)
            'Place the address of this occurrence in the next cell down in the column that holds found values (i column)
            Cells(foundmatrixCounter, 9).Value = foundRange.Address
            'Increment the loop counter for the i column
            foundmatrixCounter = foundmatrixCounter + 1
            'The Loop ends on reaching the first occurrence of datatoFind
        Loop Until foundRange.Address = strFirstAddress
    End If
    Cells(1, 9).Value = foundmatrixCounter 'Put the total number of instances, in this case foundmatrixCounter, in Z1
Next sheetCounter

If foundRange Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ("Value not found")
Sheets(currentSheet).Activate
End If
End Sub
```

There might be some other errors as well, I'm fairly new to VBA. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Well for starters you are missing an `Else` after `If datatoFind = "" Then Exit Sub` line...

Comment: Why is an Else statement necessary? If the If statement is false then it will be skipped, correct? I would only right an Else statement either for clarity or if I had an If Else statement.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php

Comment: Either an Else or you would need to close your If statement with an `End If` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumps all addresses for cells that contain your data into a new worksheet called "Results".  Clears results page before each search.

```
Sub Find_Data()

Dim datatoFind As String
Dim CurSht As Worksheet, wsTest As Worksheet
Dim rangeSearch As Range, cel As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
Dim FoundCount As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsTest = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set wsTest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Results")
On Error GoTo 0

If wsTest Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets.Add.Name = "Results"
End If

datatoFind = InputBox("Please enter the value to search for")
If datatoFind = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else

'Clear the Results Sheet
Sheets("Results").Cells.Clear

FoundCount = 0
For Each CurSht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If CurSht.Name = "Results" Then
        'Do Nothing
    Else
        Set rangeSearch = CurSht.Range("B2:X100")
        For Each cel In rangeSearch
            If cel.Value Like "*" & datatoFind & "*" Then
                LastRow = Sheets("Results").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Sheets("Results").Range("A" & LastRow).Value = cel.Address
                FoundCount = FoundCount + 1
            End If
        Next cel
    End If
Next CurSht
Sheets("Results").Range("A1").Value = FoundCount & " values found of " & datatoFind

If FoundCount = 0 Then
MsgBox (datatoFind & " not found")
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("Results").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem here is that the cell value might not be exactly datatoFind. I need to include instances where datatoFind is only a word or two inside an entire cell of words. The .Find method seems more prudent for that reason and the reason of speed.

Comment: nice one @Chrismas007 going to save your code just to have as future reference